# About Future.firstCompletedOf and Garbage Collect mechanism

Tags: scala, concurrency, garbage-collection, jvm, future

I've encountered this problem in my real-life project and proved by my testing code and profiler. Instead of pasting "tl;dr" code, I'm showing you a picture and then describe it.
[image]

Simply put, I'm using `Future.firstCompletedOf` to get a result from 2 `Future`s, both of which have no shared things and don't care about each other. Even though, which is the question I want to address, **the Garbage Collector cannot recycle the first `Result` object until both of the `Future`s finished**.

So I'm really curious about the mechanism behind this. Could someone explain it from a lower level, or provide some hint for me to look into.

Thanks!

PS: is it because they share the same `ExecutionContext`?

** Update ** paste test code as requested

```
object Main extends App{
  println("Test start")

  val timeout = 30000

  trait Result {
    val id: Int
    val str = "I'm short"
  }
  class BigObject(val id: Int) extends Result{
    override val str = "really big str"
  }

  def guardian = Future({
    Thread.sleep(timeout)
    new Result { val id = 99999 }
  })

  def worker(i: Int) = Future({
    Thread.sleep(100)
    new BigObject(i)
  })

  for (i <- Range(1, 1000)){
    println("round " + i)
    Thread.sleep(20)
    Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(
      guardian,
      worker(i)
    )).map( r => println("result" + r.id))
  }

  while (true){
    Thread.sleep(2000)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm curios about how you managed to prove that "result" cannot be garbage collected because I would say the opposite, it could be interesting. Maybe add more details about how you verified this?

Comment: Show the code. It's pretty much impossible to say what might be happening without it.

Comment: Actually, the issue is a general one and does not depend on a specific use case, so it is very much possible to answer without further details.

Comment: @GiovanniCaporaletti and TheArchetypalPaul Thanks for the reply. I'll paste my code later. However it is like Regis said, pretty plain and simple, just 2 futures and a profiler. I saw the object and triggered a GC event, it is still there. In my project, the 'result' is a lot bigger and when happened so frequently it gave me an OutOfMemory error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's see how `firstCompletedOf`  is implemented:

```
def firstCompletedOf[T](futures: TraversableOnce[Future[T]])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = {
  val p = Promise[T]()
  val completeFirst: Try[T] => Unit = p tryComplete _
  futures foreach { _ onComplete completeFirst }
  p.future
}
```

When doing `{ futures foreach { _ onComplete completeFirst }`, the function `completeFirst` is saved somewhere 
via `ExecutionContext.execute`. Where exactly is this function saved is irrelevant, we just know that it has to be saved somewhere
so that it can be picked later on and executed on a thread pool when a thread becomes available. Only when the future has completed is the reference to `completeFirst` not needed anymore.

Because `completeFirst` closes over `p`, as long as there is still one future (from `futures`) waiting to be completed there is a reference to `p` that prevents it to be garbage collected (even though by that point chances are that `firstCompletedOf` has already returned, removing `p` from the stack).

When the first future completes, it saves the result into the promise (by calling `p.tryComplete`).
Because the promise `p` holds the result, the result is reachable for at least as long as `p` is reachable, and as we saw `p` is reachable as long as at least one future from `futures` has not completed.
This is the reason why the result cannot be collected before all the futures have completed.

**UPDATE**:
Now the question is: could it be fixed? I think it could. All we would have to do is to ensure that the first future to complete "nulls out" the reference to p in a thread-safe way, which can be done by example using an AtomicReference. Something like this:

```
def firstCompletedOf[T](futures: TraversableOnce[Future[T]])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = {
  val p = Promise[T]()
  val pref = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference(p)
  val completeFirst: Try[T] => Unit = { result: Try[T] =>
    val promise = pref.getAndSet(null)
    if (promise != null) {
      promise.tryComplete(result)
    }
  }
  futures foreach { _ onComplete completeFirst }
  p.future
}
```

I have tested it and as expected it does allow the result to be garbage collected as soon as the first future completes. It should behave the same in all other respects.

Comment: Thanks for breaking it done for me, I was staring at `firstCompletedOf` for quite a long time and couldn't figure it out. And still, the conclusion is pretty against the intuition, don't know if anyone had ever complained about it...

Comment: I have added an alternative implementation that should fix this situation. Let me know if it works for you (this might warrant a pull request to the standard library).

Comment: it works fine as I observed. The threads are still occupied, but thats totally another story. Thanks for your help!