# Scala run in parallel two functions

Tags: scala, function, parallel-processing

I have the following declaration of a function

```
def myfunc(l: List[RoseTree]): Option[RoseTree] = {
   //Complex calculations
}
```

Now, I have to run this function on two huge different lists. So, I wish to run the same function, with different data, in parallel.

I have been taking a look at the Future module of Scala.

However, I also wish that when either of the functions returns a "Some(RoseTree)", then it tells the other call to stop and keep the result. Is this possible?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2):

Scala has built-in feature for this. You can use Future in combination of `Future.firstCompletedOf()`.

Please have a check at the [Scala doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#firstCompletedOf[T](futures:TraversableOnce[scala.concurrent.Future[T]])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[T]) and I would suggest to have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420697/about-future-firstcompletedof-and-garbage-collect-mechanism)

As point in the comments section, the `Future.firstCompletedOf` does not meet the requirement "cancel the futures after one is completed". You can use Monix Task (which is a replacement for Scala Futures), which support by default this. Please have a look at [this](https://monix.io/docs/2x/eval/task.html#choose-first-of-list).

Comment: I don't think that function cancels the remaining Futures.

Comment: Good point. Monix task actually support more naturally this use case: https://monix.io/docs/2x/eval/task.html#choose-first-of-list

Comment: A Future is not a Task. (I.e. it doesn't represent a running computation)